# I want to adopt cat(s) but my family has a relatively busy life. Should I? How?

Tags: cats, behavior, adoption

I'm a cat person. I just love cats. I want to adopt all kittens I see! :D

> **My background:**
>
> I live in a congested part of Nepal's capital city. I live with my
>   small family in a small house. All of us are usually busy at
>   office/college during work time (10am to 4pm).
>
> I adopted a cat a few years ago. We couldn't control him from roaming
>   outside the house (for example, he would pop out the door suddenly
>   when we opened it). After few hours, we would hear his meows and as
>   soon as we opened the door, he would rush back in (probably to eat).
>   When we returned home after work, he would meow so desperately (as if
>   he was relieved to see us). But one day, he went out and never
>   returned. :(

I recently got a call from a friend that a tiny kitten has come at his place and was asking me if I wanted to adopt it. I definitely do want. But I definitely don't want another cat to leave us like that. Does adopting 2 or more cats help prevent it? (as we can't manage a pet-sitter here) Or does neutering the cat reduces it's eagerness to go out often?

How should I adopt cats? How do working people adopt cats? Or should I forget that cats exist? :/

Comment: Was the old cat or will the new cat be spayed/neutered?

Comment: @JamesJenkins: The old cat (male) wasn't spayed. If it was female, we would have definitely neutered it. Does neutering help to control their outdoor-ness? If yes, we will definitely neuter the new cat. :)

Comment: Yes, among other benefits see our [related questions](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cats+desexing)

Comment: For people in a similar situation: Spend one thougt about getting rabbits instead of indoor-cats. If they are allowed to roam the room freely, they can be like vegan cats. They are able to be litter trained, they jump onto the sofa to be petted, they are active at day and night like cats too. But they are happy inside and can have periods with less contact if their owners are more at work (food and cleaning excluded, this needs to be basic every time!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cats have personalities. Some can spend all day alone and don't mind, others want constant attention.
Some are fine being indoors at all times, others want to roam free for hours or days at an end.


My cat for example doesn't mind being alone while I'm at work but will crawl up next to me on the couch when I get home and wants to have his belly scratched.
My friend's cat otoh is always wanting to go out and only comes home when he's hungry. He never purrs, never wants to be petted or scratched.

Comment: How long (in terms of age) does it generally take to determine whether a cat is out-going or in-staying? Anyway, thanks for your reply.

Comment: @ManishMunikar no clue. May well depend on the cat. Certainly the way they've been raised and treated as a kitten would play a big role. If they're not used to roaming outside they'd not seek it much, and if they associate the house with safety, security, food, there's less of a need as well.

Answer (score 3):

Some cats may always come back after they are let out, Some cats may not. There is no way of knowing ahead of time.

In the west we sometimes lock our cats up inside all day with litter boxes. The litter box is cleaned every day so it does not smell too much. A cat that has never been outside does not know what they are missing and are perfectly happy inside.  (though they are curious animals and may try to escape to the outside to explore)

Being an outdoor cat in a big city is very dangerous. There are dogs, mean people, cars, trucks, trains, poisons, disease, falls off high buildings and a lot of other hazards.

An outdoor / indoor cat's life expectancy is a lot shorter than a strictly indoor cat's life expectancy. This is something you may want to consider and accept.